# How do you input the `msg.value` in frontend?

Tags: transactions, ethers.js

How on earth do you input the value of a transaction? I have my entire frontend working because they all require 0 value, but my last function requires 0.02 ether and I can't get it to input in react.js. I've tried many things and I'll get errors for too many inputs. I'm using ethers.js.

I can also successfully add a value to my transaction on etherscan and remix IDE with no issue, this is only an issue with building my frontend.

Comment: Can you show the code that you want to include a valu?

Answer (score 1):

With ethers.js, you give the value in the `overrides` object with the `value` parameter. Here's the full documentation: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-functionsCall

So for example you can do: `contractInstance.myFunc(someParam, { value: someValue });`. Note that the `someValue` should be a `BigNumber` instance, so you can initialize it for example: `const someValue = BigNumber.from(123);`

Answer (score 0):

Since, we already have ethers library, we won't have to deal with BigInt.

```
{value: ethers.utils.parseEther('1000.0')}
// "1000000000000000000000
```

To tackle BigInt, one may refer to: [Ethereum Stackexchange Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/142064/how-to-input-the-bignumber-with-etherjs/142346#142346)