# How to input the bignumber with etherjs

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

This is my solidity codes, I am trying to compare the variables passed with different variables. Because float data type is not supported by solidity and function input is default tailed with 18 zeros, I use the timeAmount to multiply 10^18.

```
function setUriToUpdate(uint256 temperature) public {
    uint256 timesAmount = 10 ** 18;
    if (temperature < 10 * timesAmount) {
       uriToUpdate = METADATA_BELOW;
    } else if (temperature > 10 * timesAmount && temperature < 20 * timesAmount) {
       uriToUpdate = METADATA_AVERAGE;
    } else if (temperature >= 20 * timesAmount && temperature < 50 * timesAmount) {
       uriToUpdate = METADATA_ABOVE;
    }
}
```

When I write my unit test in js code, I don't know to pass a variable tailed with 18 zeros.

```js
await nft.connect(deployer).setUriToUpdate(15 * 10 ** 18)
```

The error is:

> Error: overflow [ See:
> https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-NUMERIC_FAULT-overflow ]
> (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from",
> value=15000000000000000000, code=NUMERIC_FAULT,
> version=bignumber/5.7.0)

Can anyone tell me how to pass big number to the function?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Convert the number into String and send it to smart contract. This happened because Javascript doesn't support number more than 53 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is failing is because of the result of `15 * 10 ** 18` is beyond what is considered a safe range in Javascript.

If you print the result of this in Javascript:

```js
console.log("Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER: ", Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

You'll get:

`9007199254740991`

Which is a 53-bit number. It has 16 digits.

If you print the result of `15 * 10 ** 18`:

`15000000000000000000`

Way bigger than the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` with 20 digits.

Check the ethersjs docs here: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bignumber/

To solve this, you have multiple options:

1. Convert each of the numbers to the built-in Javascript `BigInt` type, appending an `n` at the end of the number:

```js
...setUriToUpdate(15n * 10n ** 18n)...
```

Convert the result to a string:

```js
contract.setUriToUpdate("15000000000000000000").
```

Use `ethers.BigNumber.from` to convert each of the factors before multiplying:

```js
const fifteen = ethers.BigNumber.from(15);
const ten = ethers.BigNumber.from(10);
const eighteen = ethers.BigNumber.from(18);

contract.setUriToUpdate(fifteen.mul(ten).mul(eighteen)).then(response => {
    console.log("response2: ", response) 
});
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the overflow and you may use BigInt data type.
To use it just include

```
/* global BigInt */
```

at the top of your code file.
Then use BigInt to calculate instead of the Number data type.

```
const bigNumber = BigInt(/*smthing*/).toString(10)
```

I hope it helps!